# how to pass query parameter "as is" in nestjs?

Tags: nestjs

I have a nestJS gateway, and I need it to proxy a request from my front end to an external API.

I am passing a list of query parameters from the FE.

fe : `localhost:3333/autocomplete/prediction?test=2&toto=2`

I want my nestJs app to just get the query parameters and send them untouched :

```
  @Get('proxy')
  async proxy(@Query() query) {
    await this.httpService
      .post(`${endpoint}/?${query}`)
  }
```

problemn is, `@Query() query` return an object and I don't want to reprocess the parameters , and `@Req() req: Request` doesn't have a simple way to get the string

I just want a good way to retrieve the `test=2&toto=2`

edit : yes there is `req.url.split('?')[1]` but isn't there something built in ?

Answer (score 0):

I believe `req.search` (from [`http.IncomingMessage`](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#class-httpincomingmessage)) is the way.